# Enable AAAA queries ubuntu 14.04

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, ubuntu-14.04

I have an old arn server with ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to switch it to IPv6. the stack is working so far, I get a correct global IPv6, am able to ping IPv6 addresses, and can reach my server from outside using its IPv6.
But it seems that there is a problem with DNS resolution, when I `ping google.com` I fall on Google's IPv4.
I've done a dump of the network traffic, and I can see that when pinging, the server only issues A DNS requests and not AAAA

Do you have any idea how to enable those requests ?

Here is my resolv.conf (`options inet6` was not there originally, I tried with and without that option, with no luck)

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN        
#nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search home
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search lan
options inet6
```

Comment: First, update to a supported Ubuntu release. 14.04 is past end of life.

Comment: In general on Unix systems, order of IPs is governed by the content of `/etc/gai.conf`. Have a look in it but first, like Michael suggested you should upgrade your OS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would love to, but the hardware is not supported anymore, and I can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So keep in mind that the command `ping` is IPv4 only and thus will only ask for A records to resolve.  `ping6` will request AAAA.  A utility like `curl` or `wget` should be a better bet in requesting A and AAAA simultaneously.  This would be the simple answer to your question if it's the case...

PS: I see you have two DNS servers specified, one running on your machine itself (`dnsmasq` or similar ?).  I'd be interested to see the behavior of whatever is running on 127.x.x.x in terms of A/AAAA queries, forwarding, etc.

Comment: Good observation. I would use `wget` for this, actually my `curl` doesn't try A/AAAA simultaneously, I need to `curl -6v google.com` and `curl -v google.com`.